# Get data source of a pivot table using excel javascript apis

Tags: office-js

I am developing an add-in for excel online using excel javascript apis and I want get the data source of a pivot table in a worksheet. How can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We could use [PivotLayout.GetRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivotlayout?view=excel-js-preview#getrange--) API to get the range which Pivot Table exists on.

And more information would in [PivotLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivotlayout?view=excel-js-preview) and [PivotTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivottable?view=excel-js-preview), where could get more details about Pivot Table.

Comment: Thank you @Dongqi for the response. Actually I want to get the range from which the pivot table is created.

Comment: @TriconVinay you can use `PivotTable#getDataSourceString` for that.  You'll need to store the value of the method call as a variable, such as `dataSourceString`, call `context.sync()`, then call `dataSourceString.value` to see something like `'data!A1:I7`.  See the documentation and example here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.pivottable?view=excel-js-preview#excel-excel-pivottable-getdatasourcestring-member(1)